# Create model with its associations in python shell in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to create multiple `User` objects in the shell in Django. It is associated with `UserProfile`. Now I have a default value for the `city` column in `Userprofile` model. But I would like to pass another value to it while creating. I am creating the models from a `for` loop like this:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='Bengaluru', blank=False, null=False)
```

**In shell**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from my_app.models import UserProfile

for i in range(1, 21):
    User.objects.create(username=f'User_{i}')
```

In the above line I want to give the value of `city` parameter of the `userprofile` instance that will be created as soon as the `user` is created. How can I give that inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This code will ask you to enter city manually. If you want me to change anything ask.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from my_app.models import UserProfile

for i in range(1, 21):
    User.objects.create(username=f'User_{i}')
    user = User.objects.get(username=f'User_{i}')
    city = input("city: ")
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, city=city)
```

Comment: Yes. I tried this. It works but is there anyway where I can pass the value of `city` in the line where I am creating `User`? Just like I am passing the value of `username`.

Comment: I don't get you can you explain more?

Comment: Something like `User.objects.create(username=f'User_{i}', userprofile: { 'city': 'Mumbai' })`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to the user class.

```
class User(...):
  [...]

  def add_city(self, city):
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=self, city=city)
```

From here you can just call that function in your loop.

```
for i in range(1, 21):
  u = User.objects.create(username=f'User_{i}')
  u.add_city('Mumbai')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=User.objects.create(username="f'User_{1}'), city="_user_city")
```

Comment: @Lax_Sam: I found the above way. You have to create the User first, so I nested it during the creation of the UserProfile object. Hope it help